# Dockerfile can not build jar file : Main class name has not been configured

Tags: spring, docker, kotlin, gradle, dockerfile

I am building a dockerfile for a microservices architecture (spring) but I find some difficulties.
I got this error when buidling the boot jar

```
Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

my dockerfile is

```
FROM gradle:6.5-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle.kts settings.gradle.kts $APP_HOME

COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src

RUN gradle bootJar || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean bootJar 

FROM openjdk:11-jdk
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=app.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .

ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
```

The error is in 9th step

```
RUN gradle bootJar || return 0
```

I tried to put the name of the class in the gradle file, and i got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.config.ConfigServerApp.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

this is my gradle file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.0.RELEASE"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "com.test"
version = "1.0.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR5"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-monitor")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
    mainClassName = "com.test.config.ConfigServerApp"
}
```

this is my main class (i m using kotlin)

```
package com.test.config

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
class ConfigServerApp

fun main(args : Array<String>)
{
    runApplication<ConfigServerApp>(*args)
}
```

when I launch the application from my editor it works, but when I launch it from the jar file or from docker, it does not work

how can i fix this please?

Comment: Can you share the signature of that `main` method? It should be: `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: @rph I modified the question to include the class main

Comment: Didn't realize you were using Kotlin because of the question tags. Try to change the mainClassName as `mainClassName = "com.test.config.ConfigServerAppKt"`, with Kt in the end. When using Kotlin, the real main class is generated behind the scenes with Kt suffix, you should find it in your build folder. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @rph you are right, I should add "kt" to the name of the class.. now everything works as well, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make a formal answer from my comment since it worked. As I explained in the comment: When we use Kotlin, the real main class is generated behind the scenes with Kt suffix, you should find it in your build folder after running `gradle bootJar`.

You should update the `mainClassName` to `com.test.config.ConfigServerAppKt` as shown below:

```
tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
    mainClassName = "com.test.config.ConfigServerAppKt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html?_ga=2.213172756.1484320243.1591451861-1147250830.1591024580#package-level-functions) :

> All the functions and properties declared in a file `app.kt` inside a package `org.example`, including extension functions, are compiled into static methods of a Java class named `org.example.AppKt`.

So your main method will be part of java class named `ConfigServerAppKt` after compilation. So you should change your `mainClassName` to `com.test.config.ConfigServerAppKt`.